# Generating a JWT token for Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I am experimenting with DRM in Azure Media Services but I am having some problems with the JWT token. In order to generate a JWT token for testing in https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/ I am using https://jwt.io/. In the payload box I have:

```
{
  "iss": "myIssuer",
  "aud": "urn:myAudience",
  "exp": 1710807389,
  "nbf": 1550000000
}
```

And the secret key is from what is generated in the Content key policy in Azure. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: If you need further help, pls let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the offical document with name is [`How and where did I get a JWT token before using it to request a license or key?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/frequently-asked-questions#how-and-where-did-i-get-a-jwt-token-before-using-it-to-request-a-license-or-key)

From the document, we can see [`GetTokenAsync` function](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-tutorials/blob/master/AMSV3Tutorials/EncryptWithDRM/Program.cs) to generate JWT token.

Hope my answer can help you.